# Why won't my code calculate interest correctly?

Tags: c++

In C++, I can't get the following code to calculate interest correctly. It's supposed to calculate the money like this.

1 : 1000

2 : 2050 (1000(1.05) + 1000)

3 : 3152.5 (2050(1.05) + 1000)

4 : 4310.125 (3152.5(1.05) + 1000)

But, instead, it calculates my interest like this.

1 : 1000

2 : 2050

3 : 4310.12

4 : 8142.01

Looking at the results, I really can't tell what's going on.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    bool done;
    char finished;
    int numberOfYears;
    double accountBalance = 1000;
    int i;
    const double rateOfInterest = 1.05;
    const int yearlyIncome = 1000;
    while (!done){
        cout << "Enter the number of years you've kept your\n"
             << "money in your bank account." << endl;
        cin >> numberOfYears;
        for (i = 1; i < numberOfYears; i++){
            accountBalance *= rateOfInterest;
            accountBalance += yearlyIncome;
        }
        cout << "Balance = $" << accountBalance << endl;
        cout << "If you are finished, enter y, otherwise,\n"
             << "enter any key." << endl;
        cin >> finished;
        if (finished == 'y' || finished == 'Y') done = true;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works for me. https://ideone.com/vhOO1H

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/HJ0u6fXoH works for me too?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the way you used the program. You don't reset `accountBalance` to 1000 after each calculation. Simply move `double accountBalance=1000;` to the first line after you begin your while loop.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop keeps memorizing the acountBalance. I checked the rest of the code is correct.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    bool done;
    char finished;
    int numberOfYears;
    // double accountBalance = 1000;
    int i;
    const double rateOfInterest = 1.05;
    const int yearlyIncome = 1000;
    while (!done){
        double accountBalance = 1000;  // move it to here.
        cout << "Enter the number of years you've kept your\n"
             << "money in your bank account." << endl;
        cin >> numberOfYears;
        for (i = 1; i < numberOfYears; i++){
            accountBalance *= rateOfInterest;
            accountBalance += yearlyIncome;
        }
        cout << "Balance = $" << accountBalance << endl;
        cout << "If you are finished, enter y, otherwise,\n"
             << "enter any key." << endl;
        cin >> finished;
        if (finished == 'y' || finished == 'Y') done = true;
    }
    return 0;
}
```